# access object instance variables scope within anonymous function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I don't know how to access the plugin 'options' for this specific instance within the anonymous function after fadeOut completes.

Within the anonymous function 'this' represents the jquery element, how do I access 'options.name"?

This is the plugin 'plugin.js':

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    'use strict';

    var plugin = 'box',
        defaults = {
            wight: 26,
            color: 'white'
        };

    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.plugin = plugin;

        this.element = element;

        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        $(this.element).fadeOut(1000, function () {
            console.log(this.options.name);          // <- how do I access options.name?
        });
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {
        f: function () {
            console.log(this.options.name);
        }
    };

    $.fn[plugin] = function (argument) {
        var method = argument,
            options = argument;

        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + plugin)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + plugin, new Plugin(this, options));
            } else if ($.isFunction(Plugin.prototype[method])) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + plugin)[method](Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
            } else {
                console.error('unknown method ' + method);
            }
        });
    };
}(jQuery, window, document));
```

This is 'index.html':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-overflow">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>Table example</title>

        <!-- jqwidgets styles -->
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>

        <!-- jquery framework -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib-scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <!-- script -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#id-a').box({ name: 'aaaa' });
                $('#id-b').box({ name: 'bbbb' });
                $('#id-a').box('f');
                $('#id-b').box('f');
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="id-a"></div>
        <div id="id-b"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways, change the scope of the lambda function (with [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)), or create an independent reference to the variable and bring it into the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures):

**1: With Bind**

```
$(this.element).fadeOut(1000, function () {
    console.log(this.options.name);          // <- how do I access options.name?
}.bind(this));
```

Quote:

> Creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to
>   the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any
>   provided when the new function is called.

*OR*

**2: As a Closure**

```
var that = this;
$(this.element).fadeOut(1000, function () {
    console.log(that.options.name);          // <- how do I access options.name?
});
```

Quote:

> Closures are functions that refer to independent (free) variables. In
>   short, variables from the parent function of the closure remain bound
>   from the parent's scope.

See also [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope).